# send int value from activity one to activity two

Tags: android, android-intent, bundler

Hi I'm trying to send `int` value from activity one to activity two using this code

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ChromaDialog.Builder()
                    .initialColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                    .colorMode(ColorMode.ARGB)
                    .indicatorMode(IndicatorMode.HEX)
                    .onColorSelected(new OnColorSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onColorSelected(@ColorInt int color) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Hackpage.class);
                            intent.putExtra("intVariableName", color);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"color :"+Integer.toHexString(color),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ChromaDialog");


        }
    });
}
```

but I have a problem in value i get 0

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hackpage);
    Texthack = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hacktext);
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
    Texthack.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+Integer.toHexString(intValue )));
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: your implementation seems correct!

Comment: @VladMatvienko  i get 0 in intValue instead of color value

Comment: what do you get from toast?

Comment: show alittle more code, including a `startActivity` call, and the onCreate method of `Hackpage`

Comment: @lukaspp toasat show me the correct value of color 
but intValue  gives me 0 in value

Comment: Are you sure color value is an int?

Comment: @lukaspp yes i'm sure That's why i converted it in HEX

Comment: `show alittle more code, including a startActivity call, and the onCreate method of Hackpage`

Comment: @VladMatvienko please see my update

Comment: Are you sending using "startActivity" ? @pic

Comment: @KerimFIRAT `startActivity(intent)`  i don't want to start second activity

Comment: What I see is that you are not using the intent properly. Did you try to set the Bundle for who is implementing the protected void onCreate. Let me know and I can sent you the know how. BTW the onCreate is related with which Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//global:
static final String SOME_ACTION = "com.example.test.myapplicationtest.SOME_ACTION";
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION); //youre project package name. example "com.example.yourprojectpackagename.SOME_ACTION".



       @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new ChromaDialog.Builder()
                .initialColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
                .colorMode(ColorMode.ARGB)
                .indicatorMode(IndicatorMode.HEX)
                .onColorSelected(new OnColorSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onColorSelected(@ColorInt int color) {
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SOME_ACTION);
            intent.putExtra("intVariableName", color);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"color :"+Integer.toHexString(color),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ChromaDialog");
    }
});
```

}

```
     ///
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       int value =  intent.getIntExtra("intVariableName",0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

it's works well.
Sending value to existing Activiy. (example. MainActivity.java).
So you do not need to use Hackpage.class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting default value for your key
Check your color variable to be int, It might be long.
if it is long you can get it by `getIntent().getLongExtra(your_key, default_value)`

Comment: did you check te value of color if it is not empty? or is it an integer?

Comment: as you said i getting default value 0 My problem is not with color value

Comment: the default value will be given when your value is not the same type you are asking or it is empty, so you should check for these two possibilities

Comment: i'm pretty sure i have the same type , please see my question update